# ParseUI iOS Framework Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and have downloaded their new Framework package and implemented it into my existing iOS project.

When attempting to build the project I get 6 Mach-O Linker Errors from the PF_Twitter file. So I re-read the docs and tutorials and downloaded Parse's Starter Project.

The starter project wont build either, it gives the same 6 Mach-O Errors.

I researched for two days and have not found an answer or anyone talking about this issue. I found some help regarding the Architectures in Build Settings but the errors remain.

The same 6 errors from both my application and Parse's starter application.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I comment out  the errors go away and both projects build. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't imported `Accounts.framework` and `Social.framework`. Head into your Build Phases section of your project, expand the Link Binaries with Libraries section, click the + below the libraries, and add `Accounts.framework` and `Social.framework`.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself a lot of hassle by installing it through cocoapods.

It will add all the dependencies for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add all these libraries to make ParseUI build.  I understand that cocoaPods takes care of all these dependencies, but I don't want to depend on yet another 3rd-party package and use workspaces.  It's strange that Parse doesn't mention these dependencies in the README file on Github.

Bolt.Framework is included in the Parse SDK.

[image]